# How to pass a column name in a for loop concatenating i with a string?

Tags: r

I need to subset a data frame in several others based in the values of several columns of the original data frame.

Here's my for loop:

```
for (i in 1:qtde_erros_esti){
  
  temp_esti <- erro_esti[(paste0("erro_esti$" , "erro", i) == "1"),]
  assign(paste0("erro", i,"_esti"), temp_esti)
  rm(temp_esti)
}
```

The last piece of the puzzle for me is to pass the column name which value I must check (1st line in the for loop).
I'm trying to pass it with the function paste0, but the result of the function is a string that will never be equal to "1", hence never getting any data.

How can I pass the column names (erro_esti$erro1, erro_esti$erro2, and so on...) in this case?

Observation: I'm aware that this may not be the best approach using R, but I'm a noobie, coming from SAS, so I have limited knowledge.

Secondary question: is the way that I formulated the question (topic title) good? Accepting criticism on that too, please, aiming to improve future questions.

Thanks in advance for anyone who take some time to read this.

Comment: Hi Leonardo, it would be great if you provide a sample of you data frame, and what is the output you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `[[` instead of `$` to subset the column dynamically

```
erro_esti[[paste0("erro", i)]]
```

-full code

```
for(i in seq_len(qtde_erros_esti)) {
     temp_esti <- erro_esti[erro_esti[[paste0("erro", i)]] == 1,]
     assign(paste0("erro", i,"_esti"), temp_esti)
     rm(temp_esti)
 }
```

Comment: An additional question, if you may: and if instead of erro_esti[[paste0("erro", i)]] I wanted to check if the content of a list item where equal to 1? Suppose if I check lista_erros_esti[[1]], it's contents are "Erro1". How can I pass it as the data frame column and not a string?

Comment: @LeonardoJanuario This line `erro_esti[[paste0("erro", i)]] == 1` checks that condition.  If you want to check if there are any elements of 1, then use `1 %in% erro_esti[[paste0("erro", i)]]` or `any(erro_esti[[paste0("erro", i)]] ==1)`

Comment: @LeonardoJanuario Based on the code, I think the column name is "error1", "erro2", etc.  Are you saying that the values are "Erro1", ?

Comment: I know. I edited the question, accidentally hitted enter. In the end, I may work with a list, because one of the columns I'm checking does not follow a sequence. For example, I have erro4 and erro4A. So instead of calling as in your answer, I would need to put the columns names in a list, so I can work with a sequence.

Comment: @LeonardoJanuario Assuming that `qtde_erros_esti` is the number of columns of that data, the `i` corresponds to the column index.  We can directly use `temp_esti <- erro_esti[erro_esti[[colnames(erro_esti)[i]]] ==1,]`

Comment: @LeonardoJanuario Or if you are only subsetting columns that starts with 'erro' as prefix in column names. `nm1 <- grep("^erro", names(erro_esti), value = TRUE); for(nm in nm1) {temp_esti <- erro_esti[erro_esti[[nm]] == 1,];...}`

Comment: To make it complete, I have the following collumns: erro1, erro2, erro3, erro4, erro4A, erro5, erro6 ... erro16. In total, 17 collumns, but because of this column erro4A, the code won't work for all the cases that I need. Instead, I createad a list, so I can have a numeric sequence from 1:17, but I can't get to call the column name through invoking ```lista_erros_esti[[i]]``` instead of ```erro_esti[[paste0("erro", i)]]```.

Comment: @LeonardoJanuario Try with either the `grep` approach or the one I showed in `temp_esti <- erro_esti[erro_esti[[colnames(erro_esti)[i]]] ==1,]` (assuming all columns in datasets are used)

Comment: Thanks a ton again, I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably going about things a bit too complicated most likely, considert his approach:

```r
for (i in 1:qtde_erros_esti){

    column.name <- paste0("erro", i)

    column.data <- erro_esti[, column.name ]

    ## do things with the column.data vector here

}
```

Now you can do what needs to be done with the data from column i, using the `column.data` variable.

If you just want to work with every column of your data.frame, also consider this further simplified pattern:

```r
for( column.data in erro_esti ) {

    ## work with column.data here

}
```

You can just iterate over the columns of erro_esti directly, no need to use a counter, unless you need that counter for something else.

Comment: Notice - it is rare that one has to use `assign()`. Hearing that you are a beginner in R, you probably just need a way to refer to the column of data, as shown above.

Comment: Notice also - akrun above suggests using [[ ]] to refer to named elements of a data.frame. This is perfectly legal and works because data.frames are also lists (just with more structure to them), and lists use the [[ ]] notation to index individual elements (such as vectors in this case). the [ ,  ... ] syntax works because data.frame are also 2-dimensional objects with rows and columns. Which one you prefer I guess depends largely on how you look at the world.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, really. Even though I now a problem can be tackled with several approaches, I could not figure it out how to take yours to my problem specifically.

Comment: The explanation about data.frame working as list was enlightening. Without it, I would not understand completely the answer given by akrun.